# Ruby on Rails inflections not working with underscore character "_"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm developing an application in Portuguese, and I have the class `ContaPagar` (which translates to Accounts Payable in English), which generates the `conta_pagar` relation by default.

I want to create a plural for that, so that I can use it on a has_many relationship. The plural should be on the word "Conta" (Account), so it should be `contas_pagar`, however I tried that and it didn't work:

```
inflections.rb
    inflect.irregular 'conta_pagar', 'contas_pagar'

class FaturaPagar < ActiveRecord::Base  
    ...
    has_many :contas_pagar
end
```

.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method 'contas_pagar' for #< FaturaPagar:0x007f39604ddf50>
```

It only works when I declare it on singular:

```
class FaturaPagar < ActiveRecord::Base  
    ...
    has_many :conta_pagar
end
```

However I know the inflection is working when I try it on the console:

```
irb(main):018:0> "conta_pagar".pluralize
=> "contas_pagar"
irb(main):019:0> "contas_pagar".singularize
=> "conta_pagar"
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a limitation?

Comment: What do you do when that error is raised? Can you post the full error trace?

Comment: Inflections work on console without restarting your server. However, to make them active on runtime environment, you need to restart your server.